# yeoman 1.0 - make development server accept POST calls

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman

I'm using yeoman for my application which consists of 2 parts - client site with js/html/css and the rest service.

During development I start rest service in Eclipse and start server for my static files with

```
grunt server
```

The problem is that I have to do a post request to root url '/' (it's a fake login POST request to make browsers prompt to save passwords).

It worked with yeoman 0.9 but after updating I get:

```
Cannot POST /
```

Is there a way to configure grunt server task to accept POST requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the connect-rest middleware.

https://github.com/imrefazekas/connect-rest
    npm install connect-rest --save-dev

Edit Gruntfile.js, at the top

```
var restSupport = require('connect-rest');
   restSupport.post( { path: '/savequestion'}, function(req, content, next){
   next(null, {result: 'OK'});
});
```

In your connect or livereload middleware section:

```
        livereload: {
            options: {
                middleware: function (connect) {
                    return [
                        lrSnippet,
                        mountFolder(connect, '.tmp'),
                        mountFolder(connect, yeomanConfig.app),
                        restSupport.rester( {'context': '/forms'} ),
                        rewriteRulesSnippet, // RewriteRules support
```

The key part is "restSupport.rester()", remove the context if you don't want it.

This simple function should just reply with the json object {result: 'OK'} to everything you post to /forms/savequestion .  It should at least let you build out scaffolding in grunt server :9000 mode before you have build your templates.  Without this you would have to $.get() each $.post() and then change it during or after the build.

Comment: You can probably configure the top function to return whatever is in ?result so you can rapidly test errors as well as OK responses.